# Nginx Proxy Manager proxy localhost app on the same VPS not working

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, ubuntu-22.04

New to Nginx Proxy Manager so not sure if this should work or not, or I have done something wrong.

I have successfully installed and run Nginx Proxy Manager in docker container on my Oracle Cloud Ubuntu VPS using the default docker compose setting:

```
version: '3.8' services:   app:
    image: 'jc21/nginx-proxy-manager:latest'
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '81:81'
      - '443:443'
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data
      - ./letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
```

I can access NPM admin portal using my VPS public IP address & port 81 and create Host Proxy.

Now I have a basic .Net core web app running at 127.0.0.1:5050 on my vps as a service and I want to create a Proxy Host for test.exmaple.com to connect to it.

So I

- created test.exmaple.com in my DNS provider pointing to my VPS public IP address;
- created Host Proxy:

  Domain Name = test.example.com

  Scheme* = http

  Forward Hostname / IP* = localhost

  Forward Port * = 5050

However when i access test.exmaple.com, I got 502 Bad Gateway (openresty) error page.

I tried 127.0.0.1, my VPS private IP address and VPS hostname in Forward Hostname/IP field but none of them work.

On my VPS i can run curl to get the test page content so the app is up and running:

```
curl http://localhost:5050
or 
curl http://127.0.0.1:5050
```

If I use private IP or hostname in curl command,

```
curl http://{private_ip}:5050
or 
curl http://{hostname}:5050
```

then get

curl: (7) Failed to connect to {hostname/private_ip} port 5050 after 0 ms: Connection refused

In Nginx server instance, I can easily achieve this using below config:

```
    server_name test.example.com;

    location /
    {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5050/;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
```

Is it possible for NPM to proxy to a localhost app running on the same VPS host? Did I misunderstand how NPM and docker network should work here?

Thanks